# Docker 8082 port not reachable

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have configuration in my docker-compose.yml

```
  swagger-ui:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui
    container_name: "swagger-ui"
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    environment:
      API_URL: "https://my.site/swagger.json"
```

Its work on my http://localhost:8082
But I have infinite load when trying to open on production environment https://my.site:8082

```
➜  aaa git:(develop) sudo docker-compose ps
[sudo] password for user: 
      Name                    Command               State                 Ports              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                      
swagger-ui         /docker-entrypoint.sh sh / ...   Up      80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8082->8080/tcp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudflare has been blocked 8082